# unset array key if each value is zero in php

Tags: php

this is my code:

```
if ($_POST["order_code"])
        {
            foreach ($_POST["order_code"] as $key => $value)
            {
                $id = $_POST["order_code"];
                $array = array(
                    "code" => $id[$key]
                );

                $array_order = implode(",",array_map("intval",$array));
                $queries = 'SELECT tblorders.product_id, tblorders.order_code,
                tblproducts.id, tblproducts.product_count
                            FROM tblorders JOIN tblproducts ON tblproducts.id = 
                tblorders.product_id WHERE order_code IN ( ' . $array_order . ' ) 
                AND  tblproducts.product_count > 0';
                $pdoInstance = DBConnection::getDBConnectionInstance();
                $statement = $pdoInstance->prepare($queries);
                $statement->execute();
                $orders = $statement->fetchAll();
                foreach ($orders as $order)
                {
                    echo $order["order_code"];
                }
            }
```

when i use

```
tblproducts.product_count > 0
```

my out put is :

```
5417736
5417736
1899299
1899299
```

if changed that to :

```
tblproducts.product_count = 0
```

output show:

```
5417736
```

i want if

```
5417736 = 10
5417736 = 10
5417736 = 0
```

Even one of the values in the array with ID `5417736` was zero. Unset all `5417736` arrays and just show `1899299`.

how can i do it?

Comment: do you want one record for : 5417736 and one for 1899299 if yes then please use groupby clause

Comment: @FawadSaboor no , i want if `5417736` have value equal zero unset all array with `5417736` key, and then check another `$_POST["order_code"]` , for find wich product in order have zero value